# Why is my if-else-if statement not working in my arraylist?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, string-comparison

The following is my code. when I compiled it, and the program works.But it gives me the wrong output. When I print out the element of the arrayList using a loop, it prints out the wrong output. For example, "Greenville, SC" was printed out while it should be excluded in the first if- statement. 
The arraylist has values that repeated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoUber_cities.size(); i++)

{

    if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Greenville, SC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Pensacola, FL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Peoria, IL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Asheville, NC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Hattiesburg, MS"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Portland, ME"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Portland, ME"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Huntsville, AL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Reading, PA"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Birmingham, AL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Bloomington, IN"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Bowling Green, KY"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Lafayette, LA"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Central Atlantic Coast, FL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Lancaster, PA"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Charleston, SC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Charleston, WV"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("San Juan, PR"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("London, Ont"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Springfield, IL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Columbia, MO"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Columbia, SC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Montgomery, AL"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Morgantown, WV"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Fayetteville, AR"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Wilmington, NC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }

    else if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Outer Banks, NC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/90/collections/2197/removing-items-from-a-list-within-a-loop#t=201608142220004411998

Comment: Which is the input? I.e: NoUber_cities.
Also, using a for-each statement or directly using List's removeAll method would make your code more readable.

Comment: "The program works, but it gives me the wrong output" ... You may need to look up the definition of "work".

Comment: there is no input for that, I just tried to remove those strings from the arraylist, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that once you remove an item from the list, all the remaining items change index, but your code doesn't take that into consideration.

For example, say your list contains:

```
0 - AAA
1 - BBB
2 - CCC
3 - DDD
```

If `i` = 1 and you decide to remove BBB then the list now looks like this:

```
0 - AAA
1 - CCC
2 - DDD
```

But your loop then increments `i` and continues checking - now `i` = 2 and you have missed the CCC item that moved into index 1.

There are a number of ways to solve this problem. One way is to decrement the index if you remove an item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoUber_cities.size(); i++)
{

    if ((NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Greenville, SC")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Pensacola, FL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Peoria, IL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Asheville, NC")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Hattiesburg, MS")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Portland, ME")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Portland, ME")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Huntsville, AL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Reading, PA")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Birmingham, AL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Bloomington, IN")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Bowling Green, KY")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Lafayette, LA")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Central Atlantic Coast, FL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Lancaster, PA")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Charleston, SC")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Charleston, WV")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("San Juan, PR")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("London, Ont")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Springfield, IL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Columbia, MO")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Columbia, SC")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Montgomery, AL")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Morgantown, WV")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Fayetteville, AR")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Wilmington, NC")
        || (NoUber_cities.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("Outer Banks, NC"))
    {
        NoUber_cities.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to use streams in Java 8:

```
List<String> citiesToRemove = Arrays.asList(
        "greenville, sc",
        "pensacola, fl",
        "peoria, il",
        "asheville, nc",
        "hattiesburg, ms",
        "portland, me",
        "huntsville, al",
        "reading, pa",
        "birmingham, al",
        "bloomington, in",
        "bowling green, ky",
        "lafayette, la",
        "central atlantic coast, fl",
        "lancaster, pa",
        "charleston, sc",
        "charleston, wv",
        "san juan, pr",
        "london, ont",
        "springfield, il",
        "columbia, mo",
        "columbia, sc",
        "montgomery, al",
        "morgantown, wv",
        "fayetteville, ar",
        "wilmington, nc",
        "outer banks,nc");

List<String> filteredListOfCities = NoUber_cities.stream()
        .filter(item -> !citiesToRemove.contains(item.toLowerCase()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards:

```
for (int i = NoUber_cities.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

That way the indexes of preceding items will not shift and you can remove the item at index `i` without any problems. It is always best to delete items from indexed collections backwards.

### Explanation

Say you have a list

```
0: AAA
1: BBB
2: CCC
3: DDD
4: EEE
5: FFF
6: GGG
```

If you remove `DDD` at index 3, then the list will look like:

```
0: AAA
1: BBB
2: CCC
3: EEE
4: FFF
5: GGG
```

As you can see, the items with a *higher* index will shift down and get a new index. The items at a *lower* index will stay put.

Now, if you iterate *forward*, and the current index is 3, then the next index is 4, which, after the removal, points to `FFF`. This means you never examined `EEE`.

OTOH, if you iterate *backward*, the next index is 2, and that still contains `CCC`. (Note that you already examined the higher indexes, so it doesn't matter if these get new indexes). The size of the array changed, but the indexes of the items at a lower index than the deletion point do not change.

Comment: why doesn't it cause any problems? Even though I remove the element from list backward, the size of the arraylist keeps changing as it removes elements.

Comment: Because, as I said, the *preceding* items (i.e. items at a lower index) will not shift down, so the index is still valid on the next iteration. Try it. This is a very simple and well known principle.

Comment: @RonLi: If you move **forward**, and `^`is the current index, then `A B C ^D E F G` will change into `A B C ^E F G`, and on the next iteration, the index will be pointing at `F`, which means you skipped `E`. But when you go **backward**, the index will point at `C`, just as if you hadn't removed `D`, which is fine. The size of the arraylist is only queried once, at the start of the loop. Try it and see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are skipping elements from list after you removed original element; as elements are moving upwards after removing original element.

You can consider using `iterator` as well  as alternative to other given answers:

```
List<String> citiesToRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
    citiesToRemove.add("greenville, sc");
    citiesToRemove.add("pensacola, fl");
    citiesToRemove.add("peoria, il");
    citiesToRemove.add("greenville, sc");
    citiesToRemove.add("asheville, nc");
    citiesToRemove.add("greenville, sc"); --Duplicate element
    System.out.println(citiesToRemove);
    Iterator<String> itr = citiesToRemove.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
        if (itr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("greenville, sc")||
                itr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("peoria, il"))
            itr.remove();

    System.out.println(citiesToRemove);
```